# Github actions How to only run a step when merging into master

Tags: github-actions

I have been trying to get this right for hours, and nothing I have managed to find has helped. I am trying to setup a github action that will run tests on every pull request into master and any changes to the master branch, but only run the deploy step when there are changes to the master branch.

Here is a simple reproduction of what I am trying to do.

```
name: Main
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Test
        run: echo "running tests"
      - name: Deploy
        run: echo "Deploying"
        if: github.head_ref == 'main'
```

I have tried multiple conditionals I have found here / on other forums, I have tried moving the `if` statement above and below `run` I am completely out of ideas. Everything I have tried either runs the deploy step on both pull request and merge or skips the deploy step on both pull request and merge.

Comment: Why not have a separate action script for the deployment?

Comment: Would you be able to show an example of how to do this? When I attempted this I was still in the same position. I was using the work flow to trigger  the separate script, however i couldn't get it to trigger conditionally

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding something, but script1 could be building on push and PR, while script2 builds and deploys on push? Perhaps a bit naive and somewhat inefficient (build steps need to be in 2 places), but seems to work fine.

Comment: I did manage to find a condition that works. github.event_name == 'master'

Answer (score 7):

Just use:

`github.ref == 'refs/heads/master'`

or:

`github.ref == 'refs/heads/main'`

Depending on which branch you want to check

Answer (score 3):

This is what I do:

```
build:
    runs-on: [...]
    steps:
      - name: Echo on merging to master
        if: ${{ github.ref == 'refs/heads/master' }}
        run: echo "I'm merging!"
```